# Using WCF Services with PHP

Tags: php, wcf

I used to work with Asp.net, but it's my 3rd day learning php...

I want to use a very very basic example of WCF web-service and consume it from a php website. I took this example : [Using WCF Services with PHP](http://richardneililagan.com/2011/05/calling-wcf-web-services-via-php/)

I'm pretty sure I did everything the way it was shown, here is the php code :

```
<?php

$wcfClient = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Translation/Service1/?wsdl');

$args = array('text' => 'Hello World');
$response = $wcfClient->ENtoJP($args);

echo $response->ENtoJPResult;
?>
```

But I still have the following error in the page :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. in C:\wamp\www\geogram.php:6 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('http://localhos...', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0) #1 C:\wamp\www\geogram.php(6): SoapClient->__call('ENtoJP', Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\geogram.php(6): SoapClient->ENtoJP(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\geogram.php on line 6

[image: Error Message]

Here is my config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Lors du déploiement du projet de bibliothèque du service, le contenu du fichier de configuration doit être ajouté au fichier app.config  
  de l'hôte. System.Configuration ne prend pas en charge les fichiers de configuration pour les bibliothèques. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Translation.Translation">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Translation.ITranslation">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Translation/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Pour éviter la divulgation des informations sur les métadonnées, 
          définissez la valeur ci-dessous sur false et supprimez le point de terminaison des métadonnées ci-dessus avant le déploiement -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- Pour recevoir les détails d'exception des erreurs à des fins de débogage, 
          définissez la valeur ci-dessous sur true.  Définissez-la sur false avant le déploiement 
          pour éviter la divulgation des informations d'exception -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

I have no idea where is the problem, or how to debug this error, please help !

Comment: Please paste the error as it appears on the web browser, it's kinda difficult to read it the way it's now.

Comment: this is exactly how it appears :( ...

Comment: Then please create an html file with that content and paste here what you see in the browser when opening that html. This will make it easier for persons that can help you to read the error.

Comment: ok, i have that error :
 Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. in C:\wamp\www\geogram.php:6 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://localhos...', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0) #1 C:\wamp\www\geogram.php(6): SoapClient->__call('ENtoJP', Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\geogram.php(6): SoapClient->ENtoJP(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\geogram.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

The soap request fails as the supposed webservice didn't return the proper content type (`content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'`). This could have several reasons, and you need to investigate which of them applies to you:

1. You specified an invalid webservice url when creating the `SoapClient` in PHP. I see you have `Service1.asmx/?wsdl` in your url, shouldn't it be `Service1.asmx?wsdl`, or `Service1.wsdl`? Anywhow, the ASP.NET project should give you the correct URL when you launch the project.
2. The webservice doesn't run, but the 8732 port is used by another IIS instance
3. The webservice is started but it's malfunctioning, you can use the `trace` option when creating the SoapClient to find out the request and the response (see the [constructor doc](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) for details on how to set it, and [__getLastResponse()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php)/[__getLastResponseHeaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php))